# Is it possible to build apps for the latest iOS using an outdated Mac?

Tags: macos, vmware, xcode, ios, development

The question is related to the XCode development. Is it possible to use an old machine like Core 2 Duo Mac Mini for building apps for iOS 12 or the future 13/14? I will only build on this device.

I know that Apple drops support for older devices very fast. Do I have to use the latest macOS to reach the end mass consumer?

The other alternative is using VMware on a intermediate Windows laptop (i7-4700HQ, 12 GB RAM), which I already have. Also I have an Apple logo sticker on it

Which is the best choice?

P.S. publishing is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just, but not for long.

Contrary to your belief, Apple fully supports their machines for 5 years after release, with partial support, including security updates, for another 5 years minimum; however, the last Core 2 Duo Mac Minis are now 10 years old & have reached the end of OS support.
The latest OS they can run is 10.13.x - which is going to be fine for the average user for another 3 years until support for that OS is also terminated.

Current Xcode 10.2.1, however, requires a 10.14.3 minimum spec, so you're already going to struggle. You would have to use Xcode 10.1 which will have a limited lifespan.

To run current macOS & Xcode on a Mac Mini you'd need a 2012 model or later.

Your alternative of trying to run it in a VM on unsupported hardware is off-topic, as it would be unlicensed & therefore cannot be supported on Stack Exchange.

Comment: As you might know, Apple dropped Mojave support for both 2010 and 2011 devices at the same time while High Sierra supported these generations. This is very fast in my situation if looking from a programmer’s perspective and not from an end user as you kindly mentioned. So, because of difference in prices between generations is appx. 200 $ I should go for a newer Macs? And the question is more connected with the XCode version. Can I theoretically use XCode 7-9 for building apps for iOS 12? Limited functionality is not a problem, I want it to “just work” and build for testing on my own devices.

Comment: Mojave demands a Metal-capable GPU; that's why entire generations were dropped simultaneously. That is usually the case when support ends, it's that the older hardware is simply no longer capable. Re Xcode, each version will have a maximum macOS/iOS it can support, this time it's that Swift 3 will no longer be accepted shortly. Apple likes its coders to be up to date, more-so than the average user.

Comment: I agree that these devices are not Metal-capable. But these changes are really strange and cannot be predicted earlier (I think that no one would buy a PowerMac G5 in 2005-2006 if everyone have known that Apple will kill it). You never know, maybe the next generation Macs will be ARM and not x86_64, huh?) Ok, do you know if Swift Playgrounds is a good alternative to XCode or it’s just an app for kids? Can I test my applications on it or I must use a Mac? Personally, I need to use an interface builder

Comment: Re: G5s - You're missing the "5+5-year-lifespan" which is & has always been pretty much the case. I used my late 90s G4 well into 2008. What killed those off eventually was not just the switch to Intel, but the switch to entirely 64-bit architecture. Re: Swift - I've never used it, can't comment sorry.